# when is an expression in a lambda function evaluated?

Tags: c++, lambda

Given this little snippet: a and b are not known at compile time. Map is a mapping function for the vector, mapping the lambda function over each element of bar. Supposing fooify() is called ... Will a/b be evaluated as a constant before executing map() or will it be evaluated every time the lambda is called?

```js
Foo::fooify(vector<float>& bar){
  float a = getA();
  float b = getB();
  map(bar, [&](float c){c*(a/b);});
}
```

Comment: How could you tell the difference? And if you can't tell the difference, then what are you actually asking?

Comment: The difference is that in the first case, there would be one division operation and in the second there would be 2 million. I can skirt the problem easily by simply performing the calculation beforehand, I just want to know what's actually going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `a/b` will be evaluated in every call to the lambda function. You can make sure that it is evaluated only once by using:

```
Foo::fooify(vector<float>& bar){
  float a = getA();
  float b = getB();
  float ab = a/b;
  map(bar, [](float c){c*ab;});
}
```